# Finding lists with no intersections

Tags: list-manipulation

Lets say I have this list

```
jm = Union[Sort /@ Permutations[Range[9], {3}]]
```

which contains all sorted triplets with numbers 1-9

> {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 6}, {1, 2, 7}, {1, 2, 8}, {1,
>      2, 9}, {1, 3, 4}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 3, 8}, {1, 
>     3, 9}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 5,
>      6}, {1, 5, 7}, {1, 5, 8}, {1, 5, 9}, {1, 6, 7}, {1, 6, 8}, {1, 6, 
>     9}, {1, 7, 8}, {1, 7, 9}, {1, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 5}, {2, 3, 
>     6}, {2, 3, 7}, {2, 3, 8}, {2, 3, 9}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 4, 6}, {2, 4, 
>     7}, {2, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 9}, {2, 5, 6}, {2, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 5, 
>     9}, {2, 6, 7}, {2, 6, 8}, {2, 6, 9}, {2, 7, 8}, {2, 7, 9}, {2, 8, 
>     9}, {3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 6}, {3, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 8}, {3, 4, 9}, {3, 5, 
>     6}, {3, 5, 7}, {3, 5, 8}, {3, 5, 9}, {3, 6, 7}, {3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 
>     9}, {3, 7, 8}, {3, 7, 9}, {3, 8, 9}, {4, 5, 6}, {4, 5, 7}, {4, 5, 
>     8}, {4, 5, 9}, {4, 6, 7}, {4, 6, 8}, {4, 6, 9}, {4, 7, 8}, {4, 7, 
>     9}, {4, 8, 9}, {5, 6, 7}, {5, 6, 8}, {5, 6, 9}, {5, 7, 8}, {5, 7, 
>     9}, {5, 8, 9}, {6, 7, 8}, {6, 7, 9}, {6, 8, 9}, {7, 8, 9}}

I want to make a program that finds me an instance of three triplets which contain ALL numbers from 1-9

I only want just ONE triplet of triplets
(and I don't care about their position in the list)

i.e.
any result like

> {1,6,7},{2,4,5},{3,8,9}
>   would be OK

I tried checking all triplets like

```
Length[Union@Flatten[{jm[[i]], jm[[j]], jm[[k]]}]] ==9
```

but it takes forever for bigger lists 
(in fact I am searching in much bigger lists for 5 triplets}

I also tried

```
FindInstance[
Length@Intersection[jm[A], jm[B], jm[C]] == 0 && 
0 < {A, B, C} < Length@jm, {A, B, C}, Integers]
```

which worked but it only compares AB and BC and not AC

Is there a way to get just one example of three elements containing all numbers?

of course the program must search in my list jm

Comment: Would `jl = jm; Reap[Do[Sow[t = RandomChoice[jl]]; jl = Select[jl, FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ t] &], {3}]][[-1, 1]]` work here?

Comment: It worked fine even in my bigger list when I changed 3 to five.Many thanks.Post an answer if you like and I will accept it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
DeleteDuplicates[RandomSample @ jm, Intersection @ ## =!= {} &]
```

> {{2, 7, 8}, {1, 5, 9}, {3, 4, 6}}

In versions 10.0+, you can also use `IntersectingQ` as the second argument of `DeleteDuplicates`:

```
DeleteDuplicates[RandomSample@jm, IntersectingQ]
```

> {{2, 3, 5}, {6, 7, 8}, {1, 4, 9}}

Answer (score 3):

for the example it is not too unreasonable to just generate all of them and pick one:

```
Select[ Subsets[jm, {3}] , Union@Flatten@# == Range[9] & ] ; (*280 results*)
RandomChoice[%]
```

> {{1, 5, 9}, {2, 3, 4}, {6, 7, 8}}

Here is a way to avoid generating all the subsets:

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
jm = Union[Sort /@ Permutations[Range[9], {3}]];
While[ Union@Flatten[x = RandomKSubset[jm, 3]] != Range[9]]; x
```

> {{1, 8, 9}, {2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7}}

Aside I'm puzzled why there is no `NthKSubset` function in `Combinatorica` ?

note for this specific example you could do this as well:

```
Sort /@ Partition[RandomSample[Range[9], 9], 3]
```

Answer (score 3):

For this size:

```
g = RelationGraph[DisjointQ, jm];
triples=Union[Join @@ #] & /@ (FindCycle[g, 3, All] /.UndirectedEdge[x__] :> List[x])
```

yiels 280 triples

Answer (score 3):

```
jm // Nest[
 Replace[#, {___, Alternatives @@ Sow[RandomChoice[#]], ___} :> 
    Nothing, 2] &, #, 2] & // Reap // Join[#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]] &
```

> {{2, 3, 5}, {4, 8, 9}, {1, 6, 7}}

```
Union[Sort /@ Permutations[Range[15], {5}]] // 
Nest[Replace[#, {___, Alternatives @@ Sow[RandomChoice[#]], ___} :>
     Nothing, 2] &, #, 2] & // Reap // Join[#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]] &
```

> {{1, 3, 7, 8, 14}, {5, 6, 9, 12, 13}, {2, 4, 10, 11, 15}}

**Edit**

Just for fun:

```
jm // #@*# &@(Replace[#, {___, 
     Alternatives @@ Sow[RandomChoice[#]], ___} :> Nothing, 
   2] &) // Reap // Join[#[[1]], #[[2, 1]]] &
```

> {{2, 6, 8}, {3, 5, 9}, {1, 4, 7}}

Answer (score 3):

One can use a [`LinearProgramming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearProgramming) approach. Using my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/161896/45431) to [Selection of lists among list of lists to maximize coverage and avoid repetitions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/161877/45431):

```
disjointMaximum[sets_] := Module[{elems = DeleteDuplicates @ Flatten @ sets, lp},
    lp = Quiet[
        LinearProgramming[
            - Length /@ sets,
            Table[Boole @ Map[Not@*FreeQ[k]] @ sets, {k, elems}],
            Table[{1, -1}, {Length[elems]}],
            0,
            Integers
        ],
        LinearProgramming::lpip
    ];
    Pick[sets, lp, 1]
]
```

We get:

```
disjointMaximum[jm]
```

> {{1, 2, 6}, {3, 4, 5}, {7, 8, 9}}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Partition[RandomSample[Range[9]], 3]
```

Comment: the list I gave is just an example. The code must search into the list jm and find an example (if one exists).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = Union[Sort /@ Permutations[Range[9], {3}]];

UniqueTriplets[mx_?MatrixQ] :=
 Module[{f, a, b, c},
  f[e_] := DeleteMissing @ SelectFirst[mx, ContainsNone @ e];
  a = f[{}];
  b = f[a];
  c = f[a~Join~b];
  {a, b, c}]

UniqueTriplets[list]
```

{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}

```
UniqueTriplets[RandomSample @ list]
```

{{4, 6, 9}, {1, 7, 8}, {2, 3, 5}}